# Internet Explorer 9 send page by email grayed out

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, internet-explorer-9, windows-live-mail

Internet Explorer 9 in Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit has the items Send Page by email and Send link by email grayed out.  The default email client is Windows Live Mail 2011.  I have used the "Set Default" dialogs to do that.  Everything else recognizes Windows Live Mail 2011 as the default, including Firefox 4.  I have duplicated this problem on two computers here.  I have changed the default email program to Mozilla Thunderbird on one of the computers, and IE9 won't let me Send Page by email or Send link by email there, either.

Has anyone gotten this to work?  Firefox is my default browser, but sometimes I have to use IE9.

Comment: Don't use IE! Use IE Tab for Firefox or Chrome!

Comment: @Andrew this isn't really the place for your anti-IE commentary.

Comment: Sorry, but I thought part of this was a complaint about a lack of a feature in IE. I was suggesting a way to stay in your default browser.

Comment: @Nicholas Ummm..... it's always the place for anti-IE commentary.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer and see if its available there. Easiest way to open it is to search `internet explorer 64` in the start menu.

Otherwise it is available here:

```
 C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
```

Comment: Thanks, did that before with same result. Apologies --- I should have noted that in my original post.

Comment: I can't even seem to find the buttons your referring to in IE 9 (I refuse to use it :P) - can you point me in the right direction so I can check if they work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert on IE (being a FF user), but have had this happen as well and running IE9 with no addons seemed to work for me, accessible from system tools in accessories (start menu).